# Single quotes in MySQL ORDER BY clause

Tags: php, mysql, sql

**Background info**

I'm a guy who isn't very familiar with MySQL or PHP, who's debugging a project that another guy wrote in MySQL and PHP :)

The website is being moved to new servers. Both are Windows servers and serve PHP through IIS.

The old server ran PHP 5.1.2 and MySQL 14.12 Distrib 5.0.22, for Win32.

The new server runs PHP 5.3.6 and MySQL 14.14 Distrib 5.1.57, for Win64

I've done my best to match the .ini-files as far as seemed prudent.

**Why did the quotes work?**

On the old server SQL queries like this seem to work:

```
$db_query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $db_table ORDER BY 'id'")
$db_query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $db_table ORDER BY '$orderby'")
```

On the new server, these queries fail unless I remove the single quotes.

Why did this work on the old server and not on the new one? Is it due to changes between versions in MySQL or PHP?

Why would the guy who programmed it use single quotes in the first place?

*Oh, and before you guys start raving about injection attacks - we're aware of the risks - this site is strictly for internal use*

**EDIT**

I found this piece of code:

```
$db_query_str = $db_query_str . " ORDER BY '$orderby' DESC";
[...code...]
$db_query = $mysql_query($db_query_str);
```

`$orderby` can be for example `dateofpurchase`.

As far as I understand, this would result in a query string that ends with `ORDER BY 'dateofpurchase' DESC`? That still looks strange to my eyes.

Comment: What is in that $orderby? The problem with injection "attacks", which we are not allowed to rave about, is not only that they can inject valid code, but also invalid code... So an unsuspecting user can enter something invalid there maybe?

Comment: Single quotes indicate a string, so `ORDER BY 'enclosed'` would order by a constant value => it's like not having an ORDER BY clause. I don't know why this has worked, maybe it has something to do with some strict mode settings. MySQL can be very lax when it comes to SQL standards (like with GROUP BY)

Comment: @Nanne - Perhaps as was a little bit too forbidding... $orderby is never set directly by the user, but rather by the programmer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has never been correct.

```
ORDER BY 'id'
```

...means, literally, "order by the word id", not the value of a column named id. Single quotes can only ever surround an identifier when an alias is being declared.

This would not produce the correct ordering in MySQL 5.0.22 or 5.1.57 (or any 5.x or any 4.x) except by chance (a table that happens to be ordered by `id` on disk because it hasn't had deletions/reinsertions/rebuilt).

```
ORDER BY `id`
```

...would be fine, and necessary if `$orderby` can ever contain a reserved word that you used as a column name or alias.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I added another code example. Could you see how that example could lead to working code?

Comment: This seems right to me. Jesper: Check that the results are actually ordered in the application in the order the query suggests. I imagine the order by clause has not worked as planned for a long time and no one has noticed. It's also possible that the results are sorted in code after the query and the order by clauses are completely irrelevant.

Answer (score -1):

I think you have to use only double quotes. Something like:

```
$db_query = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM '.$db_table.' ORDER BY "id"');
$db_query = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM '.$db_table.' ORDER BY "'.$orderby.'"');
```

PHP doesn't fetch variables if a string is delimited by single quotes http://it.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.single

Comment: No, only enclose column names with back ticks, not with double or single quotes.